# Maintaining User Data

Tags: foursquare

I'm part of a social media company that is currently integrating Foursquare into our Social CRM tool suite. Our application heavily leverages building out profiles based on the information provided to us through our venues. In your terms, you state that user data can be maintained for a maximum of 3 hours but we're looking to store (maybe a subset of) data long term to provide a historical depiction of the activity at the managed venue. Are there certain portions of the user's data returned from the API that we can store for a longer extent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

User data may only be stored for 3 hours, unless you've been explicitly authorized by the user otherwise.